# An error I can not figure out, when using stdclass, shows value as *RECURSION*

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursion

So once again I turn to Stackoverflow for help. I've been trying to crack this by myself for quite some time now. Google and old questions on here have not helped me.

So here goes.

I have an SQL query that gets data from a simple enough table with a simple query. The table has int and varchar data. The problem is with the varchar data. Everything else comes out fine, but the varchar data.
I have created an stdClass and put all the data into them, so far so good. But when I try to echo it in my website, it tells me the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in messages.php on line 53

Code from the messages.php around like 53:

```
foreach($messages as $message){
        echo "
            <tr>
            <td>$message->from_name</td>
            <td>$message->to_name</td>
            <td>$message->sent</td>
            <td>$message->sonum</td>         //This here is line 53
            </tr>
            ";
    }
```

The function itself that brings $messages here is:

```
function GetMessages($id, $other_id){
global $mysqli;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `from`, `from_name`, `to`, `to_name`, message, `sent`, `time` FROM `frei_chat` WHERE `from` = ? AND `to`=? OR `from` = ? AND `to` = ? ORDER BY `sent`");
$stmt->bind_param("iiii", $id, $other_id, $other_id, $id);
$stmt->bind_result($from, $from_name, $to, $to_name, $message, $sent, $taime);
$stmt->execute();
        $messages = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $message = new stdclass;
        $message->from = $from;
        $message->from_name = $from_name;
        $message->to = $to;
        $message->to_name = $to_name;
        $message->sonum = $message;             //this one is the problem
        $message->sent = $sent;
        $message->taime = $taime;
    array_push($messages, $message);
    }
return $messages;
}
```

Now what I'm not familiar with is this. When I do a var_dump of $messages, I get this:

```
 ["sonum"]=> *RECURSION*
```

There should be a string instead of the *RECURSION*, but there isn't and I am not able to figure out why. I've tried converting the value to string using (string) at different steps, but nothing has worked. I've tried changing the table. I've tried changing the SQL query. I've tested the query outside of PHP and know it works. I've tried everything I can think of.

Even if nobody knows how to fix it, does anybody at least know what is this RECURSION thing? Google doesn't show up much either, only something about recursive functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accidentally redefining the variable `$message` as a new `stdclass` while it already exists:

```
$message = new stdclass;
```

`*RECURSION*` occurs because you put the `stdclass` instance itself as an attribute of that same `stdclass` instance.

```
$message->sonum = $message;
```

So `$message` has a property named 'sonum', which has the value `$message`,
which has a property named 'sonum', which has the value `$message`,
which has a property named 'sonum', which has the value `$message`,
et cetera, et cetera...

In order to avoid this, simple write

```
$msg = new stdclass;
```

---

*Note that `*RECURSION*` is shown because `var_dump()` detects the recursion. Other functions may cause an infinite loop and flood your memory.*

Comment: Thank you, such a stupid mistake on my part. Sometimes one just needs a fresh pair of eyes to see the stupid mistakes. :D I'll accept it as an answer right when it lets me.